# Error InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem, every time I run my application and open Products Index it gives this error below.

`

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(int i)
lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , int[] , ResultCoordinator )
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ControleEstoque.Controllers.ProductsController.Index() in ProductsController.cs
+
List<Product> model = await _context.Products.ToListAsync();
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter<TResult>.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask<IActionResult> actionResultValueTask)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Products Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ControleEstoque.Models;

namespace ControleEstoque.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ProductsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Products
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Products.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: ProductsController/Details/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var product = await _context.Products
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(product);
        }

        // GET: ProductsController/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: ProductsController/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Description,ProviderId")] Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(product);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
        
                return View(product);
            }

        // GET: Products/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(product);
        }

        // POST: ProductsController/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name,Description")] Product product)
        {
            if (id != product.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(product);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ProductExists(product.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }   
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
             }
             return View(product);
        }  


        // GET: ProductsController/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var product = await _context.Products
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(product);
        }

        // POST: ProductsController/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Products.Remove(product);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool ProductExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Products.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        } 
    }
}`´
```

The Table Product

```
    namespace ControleEstoque.Models
    {
        [Table("Products")]
        public class Product
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage ="Obrigatório informar nome")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar Descrição")]
            public string Description { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar Id do Fornecedor")]
            public string ProviderId { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I want the page Products Index load

Comment: Since you haven't posted your `Product` entity class (or the table definition), one can only *guess* that you have a property of type `string` that's mapped to a database column of type `int`.

Comment: Given my first comment and the code you just added, can you venture a guess as to what the problem might be?